# Routing / URL generation issues

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm currently building an FAQ system which has the following URL structure:

**Parent category:** /faqs/parent-category/ (eg /faqs/products/)

**Child article within a parent category:** /faqs/parent-category/child-article/ (eg /faqs/products/how-to-build-my-product/)

I have the following routes set up:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Faq.Main",
            template: "{controller}/{parentSlug}/",
            defaults: new { controller = "Faqs", action = "Index" }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Faq.Article",
            template: "{controller}/{parentSlug}/{slug}/",
            defaults: new { controller = "Faqs", action = "View" }
        );
```

The URL's generate fine for the parent, however I'm having an issue with the child articles. An example generated URL is as follows: /faqs/how-to-build-my-product/view/?parentSlug=products

The code in the View to create these links is as follows:

```
<a asp-controller="Faqs" asp-action="View" asp-route-parentSlug="@faq.ParentSlug" asp-route-slug="@faq.Slug">@faq.Title</a>
```

As you can see the URL generated for the child article isn't formatted correctly. It needs to be /faqs/products/how-to-build-my-product/

Any ideas how I can rectify this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It  works well in a new project.Could you show all your routes or share a reproducible demo to us?

Comment: I managed to resolve the issue by changing the route segment 'slug' to 'articleSlug' instead. I have a feeling it was conflicting with another route which also used 'slug' as a route parameter.